# How should make an unlimited unique username in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I make an infinite number of lines unique? The system I'm using is currently `BIGINT(20)` but it also has a maximum limit. What approach should be taken? How do I make an unlimited number of rows unique?

Comment: Please describe the computer that will have an infinite number of rows in a table.  I'm very curious what the architecture looks like.

Comment: just curious who needs more then 18446744073709551615 unique usernames.

Comment: @EG, If you were able to insert 1 million new usernames per second, assuming you use an AUTO_INCREMENT and use all consecutive id values in a BIGINT UNSIGNED, it would take 584,542 years to run out.

Comment: Don't worry about problems you won't ever run into.

Comment: Let's see, the current world population is about 7.500.000.000. No problem for a bigint column. You can even store every single person since the beginning of the history in that column.

Comment: This must be for a new social network for all of earths bacteria-infecting viruses — it's called phagebook.com

Comment: @BillKarwin, how many years will it take if you take Moore's law into consideration?

Comment: @jarlh, Moore's Law is about transistor density, I don't see how that would affect the rate of creating new usernames.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to do "infinite", in the mathematical theoretical sense of infinite, given finite resources.

The pragmatic approach is to implement a *finite* limit that is (excuse the abuse of language here) "infinite enough".

If `BIGINT` isn't infinite enough, we could use a composite key, consisting of two or more columns. But before we do that, let's make sure we aren't solving a problem that doesn't really exist.

The maximum value for MySQL `BIGINT` (signed) is 9223372036854775807.

A little big of quick math... if we use 4 trillion id values every day, it will take over 6,300 years to exhaust `BIGINT`.

Comment: +1 for the math, most likely you will die off old age before it comes a problem or the existing application will be dismissed when version 2 is live..

Answer (score 0):

It would be best for you to use a string data type and implement a GUID with a minimal collision rate.

Doing this will ensure you have a unique way of identifying a row which is what I think your after.

Comment: Using a GUID/UUID in a non replicated environment doesn't really make sense, Besides  the primary key which be copied into other indexes when using InnoDB engine which means large index spaces required you can save it a bit when converting the GUID/UUID into `BINARY(16)`.. In a replicated environment it indeed can make sense to use GUID/UUID over `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` to make sure the id's are the same on every server.